# Can the Human body Synthesise Vitamin D from Phytosterols?

Tags: vitamins, biosynthesis

I know that the human body can synthesise vitamin D from cholesterol, but can it do so from phytosterols?

Comment: Is this article helpful? http://journal.frontiersin.org/Journal/10.3389/fpls.2013.00136/full Can you also give me a link to an article which states that Vitamin D is synthesized from Phytosterols in the first place.